# Why 2 distributions can not be multiplied?

Tags: distribution-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is product of delta function with itself ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12944/what-is-product-of-delta-function-with-itself)

why $2$ or more dirac delta distributions can not be multiplied ?? i mean to define a coherent product of

$d(x)$  x $d'(x)$ with $d(x)$ being the dirac delta derivative

using the convolution theorem plus regularization i think we could.

Answer (score -6):

If you mean $\delta (x) ^2$, it can be defined well as a very large positive number (infinity). Some people are shy of infinities and call the product "undetermined". It is undetermined only in one sense: it is larger than any finite number but it is not zero or any other finite number usually "ascribed" to the product in renormalizations.