# Does $\sqrt{\delta^2}$ make more sense than $\delta^2$?

Tags: functions, distribution-theory

[*What is the Product of $\delta$ functions with
itself?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/12944/19341) was already
asked some time ago. In a
[comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12944/what-is-product-of-delta-function-with-itself#comment27912_12944)
the OP states:

> I want to create $\delta(t)$ such that the product with itself is also $\delta(t)$ and the innerproduct $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t)\cdot\delta(t) dt = 1$ and retain all other properties of the usual $\delta(t)$.

I feel that I'm in a comparable situation: I'd like to have a function
$\Delta(x)$, such that

1. $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Delta(x)^2 f(x)
   dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)f(x)dx$ and
2. $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Delta(x-t)\Delta(x+t)f(x)dx=0$ for $t\neq 0$.

Combining these gives:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Delta(x-t)\Delta(x+t)f(x)dx=\delta_{t0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)f(x)dx,
$$
with $\delta_{xy}$ being the [Kronecker
Delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). I think that
following could work:

Let $\Delta_a(x\pm t)=\frac{1}{a \sqrt{\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-(x\pm
t)^2/\color{red}{2}a^2}$ (little related to the so called [nascent
delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta#Representations_of_the_delta_function)). The $\color{red}{2}$ in the denominator inspired the title and I hope it was not misleading you, sorry if so.

When I now, for example, set $f(x)=1$ and calculate
$$
\lim_{a\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Delta_a(x-t)\Delta_a(x+t)dx,
$$
I get exactly what I need. So my question is: **Is this OK, and if not can I save it somehow?**

Comment: Have you thought about defining $\Delta(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} 1_{[-h,h]}(x)/\sqrt{2h}$? (where $1_A(x)$ is the indicator function on $A$)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Indeed, I have. Would this be a better choice?

Comment: I have no idea, but it makes the integrals easier.

Comment: @draks: Are you saying you define for $\varphi \in D$: $$
\Delta(\varphi) := \lim_{a\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Delta_a(x-t)\Delta_a(x+t) \varphi(t) dt dx,
$$

Comment: @Vobo is integration over $t$ needed, since the only contribution will be for $t=0$. Then it boils down to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)f(x)dx=f(0)$. But maybe I didn't get you right. My idea was just to get an analogy for $\delta(x)$ the has some multiplicative properities, thet $\delta$ lacks, see the linked question and discussions therein.

Comment: @draks I still don't see how you actually define your object $\Delta(\varphi)$ for every test function $\varphi$. Chris has an explicit expression which I still miss in your concept.

Comment: My example is $\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{a \sqrt{\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-(x\pm
t)^2/\color{red}{2}a^2}$, as written in the body of the question.

Comment: I am afraid I can't help you. Let $\varphi(x) = e^{(-1/(1-x^2))}$ for $|x|<1$ and $0$ elsewhere. Please tell me how you define and calculate $\Delta(\varphi)$ in this concrete example.