# Integral of delta function and derivative of delta function

Tags: integration

Can anyone rigorously prove this?
$$\int dx \, \delta(x-\alpha)\delta^{\prime} (x-\beta) = \delta^{\prime} (\alpha-\beta).$$

Comment: Is the answer always the same for all of the various definitions of the the Dirac delta in terms limits of functions?

Comment: How is this a physics question?

Comment: $\langle\alpha|\hat{p}|\beta\rangle = ...$ :)

Comment: Actually, now that I wrote it that way, this has to be true. Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice to see if the theory of distributions gives the same result.  But this does sound like a math question.  Probably get better answers over there.

Comment: This is generally considered ill-defined, since you cannot multiply distributions. But maybe it can be viewed as a convolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413689/dirac-delta-integral-with-delta-infty-cdot-e-infty/1413826#1413826), I provided a primer on the Dirac Delta and the Unit Doublet distributions.

Here, we have for any test function $f$, the distribution $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x-\alpha)\delta'(x-\beta)\,dx$ satisfies the following:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\alpha)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x-\alpha)\delta'(x-\beta)\,dx\right)\,d\alpha&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(x-\beta)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\alpha)\,\delta(x-\alpha)\,d\alpha\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(x-\beta)\,f(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-f'(\beta)\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(\alpha-\beta)\,f(\alpha)\,d\alpha
\end{align}$$

We also have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\beta)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x-\alpha)\delta'(x-\beta)\,dx\right)\,d\beta&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-\alpha)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\beta)\,\delta'(x-\beta)\,d\beta\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-\alpha)\,f'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=f'(\alpha)\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta'(\alpha -\beta)f(\beta)\,d\beta
\end{align}$$

Therefore, in terms of Generalized Functions, we have the equivalence

$$\delta'(x-\beta)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x-\alpha)\delta'(x-\beta)\,dx$$

Using a more compact notation, we have

$$\begin{align}
\langle f,\langle \delta'_{\beta},\delta_{\alpha}\rangle \rangle_{\alpha}&=\langle \delta'_{\beta},\langle f,\delta_{\alpha}\rangle_{\alpha} \rangle\\\\
&=\langle \delta'_{\beta},f\rangle\\\\
&=-f'(\beta)
\end{align}$$

A similar notation is applicable where we take the distribution over $\beta$.

Comment: This doesn't compute. What if you evaluate in a different order, i.e. $\langle \delta_{\alpha},\langle f,\delta'_{\beta}\rangle \rangle$?

Comment: The two results are not equal unless $\alpha=\beta$, so I don't see how your definition of $\langle \delta'_{\beta},\delta_{\alpha}\rangle$ works. In some sense $\langle \delta'_{\beta},\delta_{\alpha}\rangle=0$ for $\alpha\ne \beta$.

Comment: @A.S. If we wish to interchange the order, we have implicitly changed the parameter from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ over which we are computing the distribution.

Comment: Then your test functions needs to be $f(\alpha,\beta)$ since we have s distribution in 2 parameters.

Comment: Why not consider both as a fixed number then? That's a much more natural assumption than assuming one is variable and the other is a parameter - especially since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not symmetric. Either both are parameters or both are variables.

Comment: @A.S. I added another development where the distribution is over $\beta$.  This will hopefully clarify.  Thank you. - Mark

Comment: Mark, it clarifies the mechanics of what follows but not the original choice to treat one of $\alpha,\beta$ as a fixed parameter and the other as a variable of a distribution. The OP treats both as a parameter (as I think was intended), so the real question is if we can define $\int_R\delta(x-\alpha)\delta'(x-\alpha)$ - or more generally $\delta\delta'$ - which is a product of two distribution with non-disjoint singular supports.

Comment: @A.S. Yes, I agree now.  Apology for not heeding your advice earlier.  ;-)) And +1 for your insightful comments. - Mark

Comment: Good. One way to make sense of the formula (as Ian mentioned) is to view it as a [convolution](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/12988/274197): $\delta_a*\delta'_\beta=\delta_{\beta-\alpha}'$ since otherwise (as a direct product) it's not defined for $\alpha=\beta$.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about how to formally deal with such things (I have long forgotten my applied math courses). One question though: if I approximate delta with a limit of a series of functions (e.g. Gaussian or others), am I always guaranteed the same answer regardless of what series I use?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And here is another answer I posted that discusses regularization of the [Dirac Delta](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372858/question-about-the-dirac-delta-function/1372870#1372870).  Please let me know if this helps.  It contains embedded links to yet other answers I've posted herein on the Dirac Delta.

Comment: I've scanned your answers. Since you use many different regularizations, it seems like I can pick my favorite and work with it without checking the others then...

Comment: @VictorVAlbert Sure.  Choose the one that best facilitates your specific problem.  And remember, I provided only a small sample of regularizations - just the tip of the iceberg.  - Mark