# Integral evaluation with delta Dirac

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I am having doubts about the following integral:$$\int \limits _{0}^{10} \int \limits _{0}^{10} \frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}\ \delta(x)\ \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$
If we apply the definition of the Delta Dirac function we should get:
$$\int \limits _{0}^{10}\int \limits _{0}^{10} \frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}\ \delta(x)\ \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int \limits _{0}^{10} 0\ \mathrm{d}y=0$$
Nevertheless, when one plots the 3D function: $z(x,y)=\frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}$ and intersect it with the plane $x=0$, what he gets is:

1) $z(0,y)=0$ for $y\neq 0$

2) $z(0,0)=\lim \limits _{x,y\rightarrow0}z(x,y)=- \infty$

so basically $$z(0,y)=-\delta\  (y)$$
and therefore:
$$\int \limits _{0}^{10}\int \limits _{0}^{10} \frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}\ \delta(x)\ \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=-\int \limits _{0}^{10} \delta\ (y)\ \mathrm{d}y=-H(0)$$
N.B. If I choose any negative number as the lower integration extremum for the variable $y$ the final result is obviously $-H(a)=1\neq 0$.
I do not know which of the two approaches is right, or if they are both wrong and in this case, what is the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us re-name the inner integral in terms of a mapping
$$
g:[0,10]\to\mathbb R\qquad y\mapsto \int_0^{10}\frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}\delta(x)\,dx=\int_0^{10}\frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}\,\delta(dx)
$$
with $\delta$ being the [Dirac measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure) *(which is not all too relevant for this question, I just wanted to clarify that whatever we do with the so-called "delta function" is rigorously defined when one [considers measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#As_a_measure))*. Anyways, we get $g(y)=0$ for all $y\in[0,10]$ (actually for all $y\in\mathbb R$) as is readily verified. Then
$$
\int_0^{10} \int_0^{10}\frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}\,\delta(dx) \,dy=\int_0^{10} g(y)\,dy=0
$$
as you correctly claimed in the beginning.

Regarding the arguments you further make there are two problems:

1. $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} z(x,y)$ does not exist as
   $$
   \lim_{n\to\infty}z\Big(\frac1n,0\Big)=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0
   $$
   but
   $$
   \lim_{n\to\infty} z\Big(\frac1n,\frac1n\Big)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{2^{5/2}}=\infty
   $$
   so the path on which you approach the origin **does matter** for the limit, which would not happen if the limit in question existed in the usual sense. (One would say that $z$ is discontinuous at the origin or that $z$ cannot be extended continuously into the origin).
2. The idea that $\delta(0)=\infty$, $\delta(x)=0$ if $x\neq 0$ and $\int_{\mathbb R}\delta(x)\,dx=1$ ís nothing more than a heuristic characterization simply to get an intuition what the dirac measure does - because no mapping on the real numbers satisfies the three above conditions at once. Therefore, one should refrain from using this for *anything technical* beyond the standard property $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\delta(x)\,dx=f(0)$ for $f$ continuous.