# Integral over to dirac delta functions of different arguments

Tags: dirac-delta

I have a Fourier-Laplace Transform over space and time that I need to compute. But before this, I'd like to average over angle $\theta$. I think averaging before the FLT will be easier than after. The integrals are: 
$$\hat g(\vec \omega,s) = \int \int_0^\infty \int_{-\pi}^\pi \delta(x-vt\cos\theta)\delta(y-vt\sin\theta)\lambda e^{-\lambda t} e^{i\vec \omega\cdot\vec r-st}d\theta dt d^2r$$.

So my question is how to do the $\theta$ integral? $\theta$ is defined to be uniformly distributed between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. I've tried doing the spatial and time integrals first but this results in a $\theta$ integral: $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{d\theta}{s+\lambda-i\omega_xv\cos\theta-i\omega_yv\sin\theta}$$ which is not 'easy'. Is there a way to do the integral: 
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\delta(x-vt\cos\theta)\delta(y-vt\sin\theta) d\theta$$
Thanks

Comment: The curves $v t \cos \theta = x$ and $v t \sin \theta = y$ intersect at $(t_0, \theta_0) = (\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}/|v|, \arctan(x/v, y/v))$. Then, according to [this formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3512481),
$$\int_0^\infty \int_{-\pi}^\pi
 \delta(x - v t \cos \theta) \, \delta(y - v t \sin \theta) \, \phi(t, \theta) \,
 d\theta dt =
\frac {\phi(t_0, \theta_0)} {|v| \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}}.$$

Comment: I see the formula you referenced but I'm not getting the same result as you. Specifically, I don't get the denominator. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Actually in this case it's simpler to write the denominator as
$$\left| \nabla f(t, \theta) \right|
  \left| \nabla g(t, \theta) \right|
  \sin \phi =
\left| \det \frac
 {\partial(f(t, \theta), g(t, \theta))}
 {\partial(t, \theta)} \right| =
 v^2 |t|.$$
Then substitute $t = t_0$.

Comment: Yes I see now it's simply a cross product. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I see now that the way to do this was in vector form:

$$\int\int\int\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{v}t)e^{-i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}}e^{-t(s+\lambda)}d^2rdtd\theta = 2\int_0^\pi\frac{d\theta}{(s+\lambda)-iqv\cos\theta} $$

Where the dot product gave a $\cos\theta$. The final answer being:

$$ \frac{2\pi\lambda}{\sqrt{(s+\lambda)^2+q^2v^2}}$$